# Consolidate Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with claims information.
I want to filter out data which has successful payment without Declining.
Ex

| T_ID | Card Number | Status | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | PAID | 100 |
| 1 | 1234 | REVERSAL | -30 |
| 2 | 1234567 | PAID | 70 |

The output of this should be

| T_ID | Card Number | Status | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | PAID | 70 |
| 2 | 1234567 | PAID | 70 |

Cancelling first 2 transactions as ID and CardNumber is same but it has a corresponding Reversal of -$30

Comment: Not sure I understand why ID needs to be the same... Have you tried `groupBy("Card Number")`, then `reduce` and consolidate any `status=Reversal` values?

Comment: I ll change the name of column, but that is for reference that it is a group of multiple column that determine a unique transaction

Comment: IMO, a "reversal" is still a unique transaction, at a unique timestamp

Comment: Yeah, please understand the intent of question! I cant share exact column names. At the end I need to know how can I get 100 - 30 = 70 as total paid from a combination of card_number and T_ID

Comment: Like I said, should be able to `reduce` a grouped dataframe by card and/or ID

Comment: Like I said, should be able to `reduce` a grouped dataframe by card and/or ID

Comment: Information provided not sufficient. If we have to automate this you are to advice on how we treat PAID and reversal. What takes precedence and based on what.... ? that's when time stamp becomes useful. What you want done is possible but not with the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

With the provided information, I have made following assumption:

1. Amount associated with `PAID` and `REVERSAL` status should only be considered. Rest to be ignored.
2. In the final output, there has to be a `status` column with value set to `PAID`.

To filter out successful payment without declining, you'll have to provide information about time stamps.

```
select
  T_ID, CardNumber, "PAID" as Status, SUM(Amount) as Amount
from
  (
    select T_ID, CardNumber,
      case
        when Status = 'PAID' then Amount
        when Status = 'REVERSAL' then Amount
        else 0
      end as Amount
    from
      Claim
  )
group by
  T_ID, CardNumber, Status
```

It's a very basic implementation but it is as per information provided.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be using Common Table Expression (Same can be achieved using Spark SQL)

```
 -- claim table
 create or replace table tx(
  T_ID number,
  Card_Number number,
  Status text,
  Amount number(10,2)
 );
```

**sample data**

```
 insert into tx values
 (1,1234,'PAID',100.00),
 (1,1234,'REVERSAL',    -30),
 (2,1234567,'PAID',70);
```

**sample query**

```
 with total_cte as (
 select T_ID, 
       Card_Number,
        sum(Amount) as total_balance
 from tx group  by T_ID,Card_Number
 )
 select t.T_ID, t.Card_Number, t.Status, s.total_balance 
 from tx t join total_cte as s
 where t.T_ID = s.T_ID and t.Card_Number = s.Card_Number
 and t.status = 'PAID'
 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be using Common Table Expression (Same can be achieved using Spark SQL)

```
 -- claim table
 create or replace table tx(
  T_ID number,
  Card_Number number,
  Status text,
  Amount number(10,2)
 );
```

**sample data**

```
 insert into tx values
 (1,1234,'PAID',100.00),
 (1,1234,'REVERSAL',    -30),
 (2,1234567,'PAID',70);
```

**sample query**

```
 with total_cte as (
 select T_ID, 
       Card_Number,
        sum(Amount) as total_balance
 from tx group  by T_ID,Card_Number
 )
 select t.T_ID, t.Card_Number, t.Status, s.total_balance 
 from tx t join total_cte as s
 where t.T_ID = s.T_ID and t.Card_Number = s.Card_Number
 and t.status = 'PAID'
 ;
```

Here is the result
[image]